# Reset row numbers after deleting an item from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Suppose I have a dataGrid as shown below: (at-runtime)

[image]

After deleting row no.4:

[image]

After adding two more rows to the datagrid:

[image]

Notice that in the first picture the row numbering is good. When I delete an item from the Datagrid, that row number is missing after deletion as shown in image 2. In image 3 you can see that I have aded two new rows but the row number 11 is repeated twice.

Here I have got numbering using LoadingRow event as follows :

```
private void maindg_LoadingRow_1(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = ((e.Row.GetIndex()) + 1).ToString(); 
}
```

After getting the problems as shown in image2 and image3 I understood that I should manually renumber the dataGridRowHeaders. So, I tried the below code in PreviewKeyDown event of the DaaGrid :

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    DataGridRow dgr = (DataGridRow)(maindg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(maindg.SelectedIndex));

    if (!(dgr.IsEditing))
    {
        foreach (var item in maindg.Items)
        {
            dgr.Header = ((dgr.GetIndex()) + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program again I could not see any changes in the output. So I thought that the DataGrid is renumbered just before deletion of the row, so I moved that code to PreviewKeyUp. There I got IndexOutOfRangeException as Selected index is reset to -1.

What can I do to get the correct numbering?

**Solution with ShowRowNumbers Property so that developers can turn on/off the Row Numbers :**

```
public class ExtendedDataGrid : DataGrid
{

    public static bool GetShowRowNumbers(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ShowRowNumbersProperty);
    }

    public static void SetShowRowNumbers(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ShowRowNumbersProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowRowNumbersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShowRowNumbers", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedDataGrid), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public ExtendedDataGrid()
    {

        LoadingRow += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (GetShowRowNumbers(this))
                    RefreshRowNumber(args.Row);
            };
    }

    protected override void OnExecutedDelete(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExecutedDelete(e);

        if (GetShowRowNumbers(this))
            RefreshRowNumbers();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (GetShowRowNumbers(this))
            RefreshRowNumbers();
    }

    private void RefreshRowNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            RefreshRowNumber((DataGridRow)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
    }

    private void RefreshRowNumber(DataGridRow row)
    {   
        if(row != null)
            row.Header = ((row.GetIndex()) + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid ......
          ShowRowNumbers="True".....>
```

Comment: If you databind again, it should be fixed.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by databind again?

Comment: Your main window shows a **GridView** control of some sort. After deleting your row, call `gridView1.DataSource = ????;` ...and then `gridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: It's WPF. In WPF I don't have **GridView** control. Its **DataGrid**

Comment: You understand what I mean, though, right? You need to reload your data.

Comment: I can't as I am developing something like CustomControl.

Comment: Columns can be sorted but a Header cannot be sorted. So, Nobody will bind ID to the row Header. Also I am planning to create a property which developer will set to true or false to show row numbers. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a more precise approach would be to handle <s>`OnExecutedDelete`</s>`OnItemsChanged` rather than trying to sync up with the delete key-press.  Maybe you could subclass `DataGrid` and refresh the rows this way:

```
public class ExtendedDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public ExtendedDataGrid()
    {
        LoadingRow += (sender, args) => RefreshRowNumber(args.Row);
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        RefreshRowNumbers();
    }
    private void RefreshRowNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            RefreshRowNumber((DataGridRow)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
    }

    private void RefreshRowNumber(DataGridRow row)
    {
        if (row != null)
            row.Header = ((row.GetIndex()) + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. I will award bounty after 23 hours as per stackoverflow's rules.

Comment: I have used ShowRowNumbers Property to turn on/off the Row Numbers using your code. I have updated my question with the relevent code.

Comment: Sorry, I have a small problem. I want my users to have a delete button on every row. When delete button is clicked the row should be deleted. I am successful to delete the row, but at that time row numbers are not updated. Can you explain me why is this happening?

Comment: @Vishal I guess using "OnItemsChanged" would cover all the bases (edited above also).

Comment: On the first attempt it seemed to work after your edited solution, But I got some problems. When I delete using delete button that I provided, it deletes the row as well as row numbers are refreshed. But It does not allow me to delete row by selecting it and pressing the delete key. So, In addition to the edited code I tried to override OnExecutedDelete. And now it works fine. I have updated my question for relevent code.

Comment: How would you actually use this - do I need to add anything in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

event name RowsRemoved. Then write below code

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {

        int cct = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; //count how many rows in dgv

        int cnt = 0;
        int replace_no = 1;


        while(cnt < cct)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cells[0].Value = replace_no.ToString(); //replace S No            
            cnt = cnt + 1;
            replace_no = replace_no + 1;
        }
    }
```